# how to style children elements in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

is there a way to select children of the element I am styling in react native?

css example of what I am trying to achieve: `div > *`

Answer (score 0):

You can use js in react so you can use

```
let child=parentElement.children
```

And then you can loop through child and add what styling you want